# Django: keep owning side unique when adding object with different ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

I have two fields, one being Symbol and the other Source. They have a ManyToMany relationship, since each Symbol can appear in multiple Sources and each Source can have multiple Symbols. Symbols are unique, too. So far so good.

Now I want to allow the user to bulk add a CSV of Symbol -> Source mappings. There is, however, the chance that a Symbol appears twice in one or more of these CSVs, which I believe will violate the UNIQUE constraint.

I could of course check while iterating through every row in the CSV whether the character is already in the database. But wouldn't that cause a load of database calls? Is there a more efficient way?

```
class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    offset = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " by " + self.author

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)


class Symbol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, unique=True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Source, through='CharInSource')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class SymbolInSource(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "p" + str(self.page)
```

Here's the bulk upload logic:

```
class BulkUpload(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
    source = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Source.objects.all())

    def save(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data['file']
        source = self.cleaned_data['source']
        file.seek(0)
        to_be_added = []
        for line in file.readlines():
            data = line.decode('utf-8').split(',')
            name = data[0]
            if len(name) > 1:
                continue  # any faulty characters
            page = data[1].split('\n')[0]

            symbol = Symbol(name=name)
            symbol.save()
            location = SymbolInSource(source=source, page=page, symbol=symbol)
            location.save()

            to_be_added.append({
                'source': location.source,
                'location': location.page,
                'symbol': symbol
            })

        return to_be_added
```

Comment: Load the csv into a PYthon data structure. Extract a set of sources and bulk create those. Do the same for the symbols. Then bulk create the symbol_in_sources. 3 DB queries.

Comment: but they may already exist in the database, too. Is it necessary to query for their existence or is there a way to insert if unique, else merge?

Comment: That's one extra query per model to get all the existing ones,

Comment: OK So I do have to query everything before inserting -- but not necessarily in the loop.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Unfortunately, there is no bulk version of `get_or_create` =)